# When using htop command, do red values in the time+ column mean there's something wrong?

Tags: linux, nginx, cpu, htop

Below is my server `htop` display. The `nginx` process uses CPU time more then 18 hours, and is shown in red color, but CPU and memory all look OK. Is the value within the normal range?

[image]

Comment: If a process has more than 1 thread, the 'TIME+' value  is sum of processor time used by the threads of the process.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was curious about this too, so I dug into the source code and found this:

```
if (hours >= 100) {
   snprintf(buffer, 10, "%7lluh ", hours);
   RichString_append(str, CRT_colors[LARGE_NUMBER], buffer);
} else {
   if (hours) {
      snprintf(buffer, 10, "%2lluh", hours);
      RichString_append(str, CRT_colors[LARGE_NUMBER], buffer);
      snprintf(buffer, 10, "%02d:%02d ", minutes, seconds);
   } else {
      snprintf(buffer, 10, "%2d:%02d.%02d ", minutes, seconds, hundredths);
   }
   RichString_append(str, CRT_colors[DEFAULT_COLOR], buffer);
}
```

So, it looks like whenever the CPU time exceeds one hour, the hour portion is just highlighted in red (or whatever `CRT_colors[LARGE_NUMBER]` happens to be.)

Notice that the time format changes as the time goes:

`4:33.42` is minutes/seconds/millisconds

`18h26:41` is hours/minutes/seconds

`101h`  would be hours > 100

Answer (score 0):

Most likely just a notification method to help you  identify processes that exhibit high cpu utilization within the load averages. Check the man page to be sure.